# How to record video from a Unity3D Android Plugin?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-camera

I have a Unity3D (2019.3.14f) Augmented Reality application that uses ARCore.
I also have an Android-java plugin that I am developing.

The plugin currently records the screen i.e. "what the user sees" and it works fine.
I now want the plugin to record video from the camera.

I've tried every way I can think of and find on SO, GitHub and other random places, but I just cannot get it to work. It's either some issue with Window permissions such as:

```
cmp=com.cambridge.audit/com.cambridge.arApp.CameraService (has extras) }: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@2133910 -- permission denied for window type 2006
```

or it's some error about the recorder being in an illegal state.

I've managed to get it *almost* working. It starts recording, as far as I can tell - it even creates the video.mp4 file... but it is 0kb in size. This is because when it tries to stop recording, an exception is thrown. I'm at a total loss - I'm not very familiar with Android, so would appreciate it if someone could help figure this out. I have all the permissions (camera, write and read storage, micorphone) as well as the service declared in the Manifest. Here is the exception thrown, followed by my code:

```
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime Process: com.something.myUnityApp, PID: 30687
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service com.something.myplugin.CameraService@a54f7ec: java.lang.IllegalStateException
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:4552)
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:273)
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2133)
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.media.MediaRecorder._stop(Native Method)
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(MediaRecorder.java:1440)
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.something.myplugin.CameraService.stopRecording(CameraService.java:156)
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime    at com.something.myplugin.CameraService.onDestroy(CameraService.java:81)
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:4532)
2020/07/30 01:38:52.908 30687 30687 Error AndroidRuntime    ... 8 more
```

Below is part of my Gradle script:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

}
```

Here is my Android Plugin:

```
public class CaptureManager extends UnityPlayerActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback  {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mSurfaceView =  new SurfaceView(this);

        mSurfaceHolder= mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        Intent intent = new Intent(CaptureManager.this,
        CameraService.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startService(intent);

        //Execute task after 1 min duration
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

              Intent intent = new Intent(CaptureManager.this,
              CameraService.class);
              intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              stopService(intent);

            }
        }, 60000);

    }

//region Camera

    private static final String TAG = "Recorder";
    public static SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    public static SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    public static Camera mCamera;
    public static boolean mPreviewRunning;
    boolean found = false;
    int i;

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                               int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {


    }

//endregion

}
```

And here is my Camera Service:

```
public class CameraService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "RecorderService";
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private static Camera mServiceCamera;
    private boolean mRecordingStatus;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    boolean found = false;
    int i;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        mRecordingStatus = false;

        mSurfaceView = CaptureManager.mSurfaceView;
        mSurfaceHolder = CaptureManager.mSurfaceHolder;
        // Getting front camera id in i
        for (i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
            Camera.CameraInfo newInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, newInfo);
            if (newInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        mServiceCamera = Camera.open(i);
        super.onCreate();
        if (mRecordingStatus == false)
            if (startRecording()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                        CaptureManager.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getApplication().startActivity(intent);
            }

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopRecording();
        mRecordingStatus = false;

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public boolean startRecording() {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Recording Started",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Camera.Parameters params = mServiceCamera.getParameters();
            mServiceCamera.setParameters(params);
            Camera.Parameters p = mServiceCamera.getParameters();

            final List<Camera.Size> listSize = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            Camera.Size mPreviewSize = listSize.get(2);
            Log.v(TAG, "use: width = " + mPreviewSize.width + " height = "
                    + mPreviewSize.height);
            p.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            p.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP);
            mServiceCamera.setParameters(p);

            try {
                mServiceCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
                mServiceCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mServiceCamera.unlock();
            mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

            mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mServiceCamera);

            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);

            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/video.mp4");

            mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
            mMediaRecorder
                    .setVideoSize(1, 1);
            mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());

            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
            mMediaRecorder.start();

            mRecordingStatus = true;

            return true;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void stopRecording() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Recording Stopped",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            mServiceCamera.reconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();

        mServiceCamera.stopPreview();
        mMediaRecorder.release();

        mServiceCamera.release();
        mServiceCamera = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you add your service and activity in manifest?

Comment: @NikolayGonza Yes, sorry, forgot to say but I do have all permissions and the service declared in the Manifest. Updated.